# Interpreting the coefficients

Tags: standard-deviation

I am reading a research paper about the effects of exposure to dirty water on test scores. The paper mentions the following:

"a 10pp increase in exposure to dirty water reduce test scores by 0.074 standard deviations, or a one standard deviation increase in exposure to dirty water reduces test scores by 0.028 standard deviations"

[image: The table is here]

However I do not know how they get that from the table they provided (see the image attached). Can someone help me with this?